# Do sunfire cape, rylai and Liandry's Torment combine with each others?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I buy the 3 items, will the damage of the sunfire cape apply a slow effect?

And will it trigger liandry's passive too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rylai triggers on 'spell damage' and Sunfire's dps isn't counted.

Liandry procs the same as Rylai.